# Delete all in FOXPRO

Tags: delete-row, visual-foxpro

This question may seem rudimentary but nothing that I have found online quite fits.

I am looking at an old FOXPRO script that we used to make a table. At the moment, I am attempting to translate this script into SQL. Of note is the following,

```
 delete all for code='000000'
 pack
```

If I understand this correctly, it deletes all rows/records where the code field has a value of 000000. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Into SQL"
What do you mean by "SQL"? 
Do you mean do the same thing using SQL in VFP for a VFP table? If so then:

```
use myTable exclusive
delete from myTable where code = '000000'
pack
```

But I doubt you are asking this, when you could do it by simply using the xBase code you wrote.

Do you mean how to that in an SQL backend like MS SQL server. postgreSQL, MySQL ...? If so then:

```
delete from myTable where code = '000000'
```

Note: In your code "all" is unnecessary but wouldn't do any harm.
Note2: In VFP code that you wrote, first line is "marking" the rows as "deleted" that have code value '000000'.
Second line really removes those rows from the table.

Comment: I am attempting to do the same task/manipulation in SQL that they did in FOXPRO in the past. thanks for the clarification about the "all" element. Every item I found online simply said "Delete" and not "Delete all"

Comment: "all" is to define the scope. But since there is a for code = '000000' there, with or without all it would do the same thing. In VFP if there isn't a for or while clause: delete (without all) only deletes the "current" row. delete all deletes all rows. delete all (without for or while clause) is like saying "delete from myTable" in SQL backends.

Answer (score 0):

What version of foxpro?

```
delete from [table] where code = '00000'
pack
```

or

```
delete for code = '000000' 
pack
```

both should work